# crear grafica matplotlib pyplot con dos variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

hola ¿como puedo hacer para que quede una barra (barh) debajo de la otra?

tengo un dataframe con esta estructura
[image: dataframe]

edito: fragmento del archivo en formato csv

```
Div,Date,HomeTeam,AwayTeam,FTHG,FTAG,FTR,HTHG,HTAG,HTR,Referee,HS,AS,HST,AST,HF,AF,HC,AC,HY,AY,HR,AR,B365H,B365D,B365A,GBH,GBD,GBA,IWH,IWD,IWA,LBH,LBD,LBA,SBH,SBD,SBA,WHH,WHD,WHA,GB>2.5,GB<2.5,B365>2.5,B365<2.5
E0,16/08/03,Arsenal,Everton,2,1,H,1,0,H,M Halsey,11,13,5,7,8,15,6,9,1,3,1,1,1.4,3.8,8,1.44,4,7,1.35,4,7,1.333,4,8,1.4,3.75,7.5,1.28,4.5,8,1.75,1.95,1.7,2.1
E0,16/08/03,Everton,Tottenham,1,0,H,1,0,H,R Styles,10,15,5,7,20,27,1,4,3,5,0,0,2.375,3.25,2.75,2.35,3.25,2.8,2.5,3,2.5,2.2,3.2,2.8,2.25,3.2,2.8,2.2,3.2,2.8,1.85,1.85,1.95,1.85
E0,16/08/03,Blackburn,Wolves,5,1,H,2,0,H,J Winter,25,8,13,5,8,14,6,2,1,1,0,0,1.615,3.4,5.5,1.68,3.4,5,1.7,3.2,4.2,1.615,3.5,4.5,1.57,3.4,5.5,1.57,3.5,5,1.85,1.85,1.9,1.9
E0,16/08/03,Wolves,Middlesbrough,3,2,H,1,1,D,G Poll,17,8,9,5,18,16,7,6,1,1,0,0,2.3,3.25,2.8,2.4,3.25,2.7,2.1,3.1,3,2.375,3.2,2.6,2.2,3.2,2.87,2.3,3.2,2.62,1.95,1.75,2.1,1.7
E0,16/08/03,Middlesbrough,Blackburn,2,2,D,2,0,H,M Riley,12,13,7,10,27,15,2,7,3,1,0,0,2.5,3.2,2.6,2.5,3.25,2.6,2.2,3.1,2.8,2.5,3.2,2.5,2.4,3.2,2.6,2.3,3.2,2.62,1.95,1.75,2,1.8
E0,16/08/03,Man United,Arsenal,4,0,H,1,0,H,P Durkin,13,15,6,5,12,8,8,4,0,4,0,0,1.286,4.5,10,1.3,4.8,9,1.3,4.2,8,1.25,4.5,10,1.25,5,9,1.22,5,9.5,1.65,2.1,1.66,2.2
E0,16/08/03,Portsmouth,Man United,2,1,H,1,0,H,G Barber,4,9,3,5,18,22,7,9,2,1,0,1,2.375,3.25,2.75,2.4,3.25,2.7,2.4,3,2.6,2.375,3.2,2.6,2.25,3.2,2.8,2.3,3.2,2.62,1.9,1.8,1.9,1.9
E0,17/08/03,Charlton,Portsmouth,0,3,A,0,2,A,M Dean,10,14,5,8,12,16,4,7,2,1,1,0,2.25,3.4,2.75,2.38,3.25,2.75,2.1,3.1,3,2.25,3.2,2.75,2.3,3.2,2.75,2.37,3.3,2.5,1.9,1.8,1.85,1.95
```

estoy intentando crear un grafico con estas dos consultas

```
x1 = dt.HomeTeam[dt['FTR']=='H'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh',alpha=1)
x2 = dt.AwayTeam[dt['FTR']=='A'].value_counts().plot(kind='barh',alpha=1, color='red')
plt.legend((x1, x2),('HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'))
```

esto es lo que se genera
[image: grafica]

Comment: Hola Colcrt!  A qué te refieres con "¿Cómo puedco hacer para que quede una barra debajo de la otra"? Por favor añade más información a tu pregunta y considera leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hola, lo que quiero es que en la grafica se visualicen esos dos resultados (barra azul y roja) para poder compararlos mejor, lo que hasta ahora tengo es que las barras se superponen una encima de la otra y me dificulta comparar los resultados, es decir que en la grafica se vea barra azul, barra roja para el primer equipo (fullham) y así para los demás

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar unos datos de ejemplo, en forma de json o de csv o en el formato que te sea más sencillo extraer? De este modo en la respuesta se podría incluir código que funcione y la gráfica que generaría.

Comment: hola, he editado el post con un fragmento del archivo en formato csv